# Decompressing big-endian xz file

Tags: embedded-linux, compression, xz

I have a big-endian zImage file that I dumped from a flash chip.

I dug through the hex dump of zImage and found an xz header (FD 37 7A 58 5A 00), leading me to believe it was compressed with xz.

```
01c2010 4d00 8c5d 0000 0000 4d00 4a60 0000 0000
01c2020 7a58 fd37 0001 5a00 de36 6922 edc2 03c0
```

How can I use dd to grab the file starting from the header, and how can I decompress the file? I'm working on a little-endian ThinkPad.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is rather unlikely that that byte sequence showed up by chance. That is an xz header.

There is no such thing as a "big-endian xz file". It is just an xz stream in that file. Simply extract the stream from the header to the end of the file. The xz format is self-terminating, so decompressing with xz will ignore the junk at the end.